# How to execute a bean method before page is rendered?

Tags: java, jsf

What is the best approach to execute a method in a bean before the JSF page using that bean is rendered?

**Update**: I am trying to execute a method which would populate some data used by the JSF backing bean. This backing bean is used in a form on a JSP page, where I need some prepopulated data.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? This is really open ended in it's current state. "Best approach" for what? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

In JSF2 you can use system Event also.

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{customerBean.loadData}"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Constructor of bean / post construct [`@PostConstruct`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) methods will do it.

But the best approach is greatly depends on the functionality you are implementing ,

Comment: there is a preRender method that I wish to call everytime the bean is invoked, are there any phase listener in jsf 1.2 using which i can use to  call this method?

Comment: `there is a preRender method that I wish to call everytime the bean is invoked` , can you expand bean is invoked

Comment: I have tried this with a `@ConversationScoped` backing bean, and I got a symbol not found error on the `@Resource private SessionContext sessionContext` I need for some of my DB accesses. This is just FYI ;)